# Getting all files in Azure file share (CloudFileDirectory)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I'm looking for a C# method that will return all files (in all sub-directories) in an Azure file share.

Have an example but it throws a run time error.   I've tried the code example below which I got from here however it throws an exception.

I have pasted the code in here but if anyone has a method that walks the entrire Azure directory get gets files that would be great.

```
CloudFileDirectory dir = fclient.GetShareReference(share.ToString()).GetRootDirectoryReference();

foreach (IListFileItem file in dir.ListFilesAndDirectories())   //.Directory.ListFilesAndDirectories())
{
    list_subdir(file);
}
```

And the method.

```
public static void list_subdir(IListFileItem list)
{
    Console.WriteLine("subdir");
    CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory = (CloudFileDirectory)list;
    IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = fileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories();

    foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
    {
        if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File.CloudFileDirectory))
        {
            list_subdir(listItem);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(listItem.Uri.Segments.Last());
        }
    }
}
```

"   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.d__1`1.MoveNext() 
in C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-split-pr-master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 82
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.b__0() in 
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\dotnet-split-pr-master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 41

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the nuget package [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/), version 9.3.3 installed. And the code below works fine for me, all files in sub-directories are listed.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string accountName = "xxx";
            string key = "xxxx";
            var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, key), true);
            var share = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("testfolder");
            IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectories();
            foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
            {
                if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFile))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(listItem.Uri.Segments.Last());
                }
                else if(listItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFileDirectory))
                {
                    list_subdir(listItem);
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("done now");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void list_subdir(IListFileItem list)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("subdir");
            CloudFileDirectory fileDirectory = (CloudFileDirectory)list;
            IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = fileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories();

            foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
            {
                if (listItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFileDirectory))
                {
                    list_subdir(listItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(listItem.Uri.Segments.Last());
                }
            }

        }
```

The directories in file share:

**root:**

[image]

**sub-directory 1:**

[image]

**sub-directory 2:**

[image]

**Test result: all files in sub-directories are listed:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that does indeed work in .net 4.6.1 console application using VS2019.  The error I posted initially was whilst I was running in LINQPad5. Thanks

Comment: I would like this to give me a list of the 17 files I have in my share, however the code I now have double counts some of the files so I end up with 29.   Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I will have to post my code as a new question as editing my original seems to mess up the code formatting.