# Azure File Share - File not found (404) even though it lists the files in my application

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

Maybe i'm calling the wrong Task action on the method since it works on an MVC project just fine. This is strictly trying to play with it on a Razor Page, not MVC.

When I call OnGetAsync() my page does indeed populate all of the files available. However, when I try to download the file, it shows file not found.

**DownloadStub method:**

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadStub(string id)
        {
            string fileStorageConnection = _configuration.GetValue<string>("fileStorageConnection");
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(fileStorageConnection);
            CloudFileShare share = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient().GetShareReference("test");
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFileDirectory dir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(@"E000002/stubs");
            CloudFile file = dir.GetFileReference(id);

            if (!file.Exists())
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "File not found.");
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                await file.DownloadToStreamAsync(new MemoryStream());
                Stream fileStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
                return File(fileStream, file.Properties.ContentType, file.Name);
            }

        }
```

**cshtml page**

```cs
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="~/Files/DownloadStub?id=@data.FileName">Download</a>
</td>
```

When I try setting a breakpoint on the method, it does not get hit, which I think is part of the issue but I don't know how to investigate it further.

To see my other implementations for this page [you can review this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63688773/multiple-constructors-accepting-all-given-argument-types-have-been-found-in-type) if it helps.

[image: View of files being returned.]
[image: Folders]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For razor pages,the page method name in razor pages is different from action method in mvc.It would be like:OnGet**MethodName** for get method and OnPost**MethodName** for post method.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#multiple-handlers-per-page

Change your razor pages like below:

```
<td>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="~/Files?id=@data.FileName&handler=DownloadStub">Download</a>
</td>
```

Backend code:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet()
    {
       //...
    }
    public void OnGetDownloadStub(string id)
    {
       //do your stuff...
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rena! I actually came across that article last night and tried the OnGet in front of the method, but I did not catch the handler extension on the route so I was still having issues. This solved it for me!